# Copy Azure Application Insights Dashboard and Point at New Application Insights Instance

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have a large AI dashboard built on top of a collection of complex kusto queries. We have multiple environments (dev/QA/Prod/Staging/etc...) with an AI instance in each.

Is it possible to copy the dashboard into all environments via ARM template or some kind of export process?

Recreating it manually in each environment would be a lot of extra work.

Comment: Yes, you can download it, modify and then upload using ARM

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can! Every dashboard on Azure has an underlying JSON representation.

For example:
[image: Azure Dashboard]

As seen in the above screenshot, there are options to **Download** and **Clone** the dashboard, that'll help with easier manipulation. Note that you can fetch the JSON representation from the [Resource Explorer](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/ArmExplorerBlade) as well.

The next step is to create a template from this JSON so that it can be reused programmatically with the appropriate resource management APIs, command-line tools, or within the portal. It's not necessary to fully understand the dashboard JSON structure to create a template. ;)

Azure offers the ability to orchestrate the deployment of multiple resources via a [template-based deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell) system. You create a deployment template that expresses the set of resources to deploy as well as the relationships between them.

Once you have crafted your template you can deploy it using the [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/resources/deployments), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy), [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/group/deployment#az-group-deployment-create), or the [portal’s template deployment page](https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template).

For detailed information on how all of this can be done, please take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically) doc.

Hope this helps!